# UIPageControl alike Android Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, uipagecontrol

Is there anything that I can use to mimic the UIPageControl in Android Phonegap? I've tried to research it but can't find any clue.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to create a screen that has some images there, each image populate whole screen, so user can slide to right or left to view next/previous image. It's just like UIPageControl behaves.

Comment: I think http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html is what you need to check out.

Comment: Hi Sweety, I want to achieve it in Phonegap Android which uses HTML and Jquery as its implementation and I don't want native code as much as possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know in HTNL and Jquery i dont think you have any control to do such. You will have to implement it on your own.  You will have to take an image tag in HTML with two buttons / handle the swipe event in  jquery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)  and then upload a new image and call redraw on the page.